Is having no general closed-form solution (the three-body problem) related to the non-renormalizability (of gravity)?
The three-body problem is nonlinear. Gravity is also nonlinear and blows up at small scales due to higher order interactions. Renormalization of the three-body problem does not make sense since there are no infinities involved. On one hand there aren't any infinities, on the other there is no general closed-form. So the counterfactual that offers itself is: could the three-body problem also be non-renormalizable if one could imagine the blow-up (infinities) manifest itself as the lack of general closed-form solution? I apologize in advance if my knowledge and/or reasoning is inadequate.

Hint: 3-mass problem in Newton gravity is closely related (up to signs) to 3-charge problem in electrostatics, which is renormalizable.
